# Getting a blank screen with no errors using Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I am following a tutorial and my screen turned blank with no error messages.  I looked in laravel.log and got this errors, but am unsure how to fix it.
Here is the error from the log file.

```
2017-04-10 14:30:40] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException: The "--resources" option does not exist. in /Users/aaronmk2/Desktop/CodingDojo/php/Todos/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php:219
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/aaronmk2/Desktop/CodingDojo/php/Todos/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php(155): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->addLongOption('resources', NULL)
#1 /Users/aaronmk2/Desktop/CodingDojo/php/Todos/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php(84): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->parseLongOption('--resources')
#2 /Users/aaronmk2/Desktop/CodingDojo/php/Todos/vendor/symfony/console/Input/Input.php(63): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->parse()
#3 /Users/aaronmk2/Desktop/CodingDojo/php/Todos/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(220): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Input->bind(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputDefinition))
#4 /Users/aaronmk2/Desktop/CodingDojo/php/Todos/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(167): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#5 /Users/aaronmk2/Desktop/CodingDojo/php/Todos/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(826): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#6 /Users/aaronmk2/Desktop/CodingDojo/php/Todos/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(190): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Console\ControllerMakeCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#7 /Users/aaronmk2/Desktop/CodingDojo/php/Todos/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#8 /Users/aaronmk2/Desktop/CodingDojo/php/Todos/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(123): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#9 /Users/aaronmk2/Desktop/CodingDojo/php/Todos/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#10 {main}
```

Comment: Make sure that `APP_DEBUG=true` in your .env file to see those errors in your browser (if that's what you mean by "screen"). But this looks like a Console command where you pass a `--resources` option which does not exist or is explicitly required. So, in order to fix this, omit/add this option or make sure your command accepts it.

Answer (score 0):

From the log file the error is telling you that the `--resources` option does not exists on the command `php artisan make:controller`.

You have to call that command with the option `--resource` (singular one), i.e.:

```
php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource
```